# Webpack stalling on my sass file

Tags: sass, webpack

I trying use `webpack` to compile my `sass` files, but I am getting this error:

```
Module not found: Error: Cannot resolve module 'style' in /Users/jason/bills-flex/js
 @ ./js/router.js 3:0-29
```

I have installed `node-sass` and `sass-loader`.  Here is the sass portion of my `webpack.config.js`:

```
{
    test: /\.scss$/,
    exclude: /(node_modules)/,
    loader: "style!css!sass"
}
```

I am `require`ing my file in the js like:

```
require('./../sass/app.scss');
```

But I get the above error.  What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 3):

In my `webpack.config.js` I had `style` listed as one of the loaders for `scss` files.  `webpack` was looking for that loader and I had not installed it yet.  I ran `npm install style-loader` and that fixed the problem.